# Sub-classed View Controller gets error 'not key value coding-compliant'

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have been trying to solve this bug for 2 days straight and can't seem to find the problem.

I sub-classed a standard ViewController like so:

```
@interface ToolbarVC : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIButton* button1;
 IBOutlet UIButton* button2;
 IBOutlet UIButton* button3;
 IBOutlet UIButton* button4;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button2;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button3;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button4;

-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) button3Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) button4Pressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

In interface builder, I wired up all the buttons to the File's owner, like normal.

In the ToolbarVC Identity inspector, under class identity, I changed the File's Owner class name to 'ToolbarVC'.

In my AppViewController, I instantiate the class like this:

```
ToolbarVC* tbvc = [[ToolbarVC alloc] init];
photoToolbarVC = tbvc; // this is my class variable
[self.view addSubview:tbvc.view];
```

The ToolbarVC inits, and in it's viewDidLoad method sets the button names and sizes properly.

However, if I try to click the buttons it crashes with 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'.  IF I try to animate the toolbar into the view like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"addToolbars" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kFadeDuration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[photoToolbarVC.view setCenter:CGPointMake(512, 200)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It gives me this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key button4.'

I've searched for two days and tried several ways to fix it, including initWithNibName:@"ToolbarVC".

What's interesting is if I don't animate it into the view, it displays, with the buttons properly named and sized (this happens in the ToolbarVC viewDidLoad method when it's created).  Only when I try to animate it, or click a button, it crashes.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need four methods (one for each button). Surely, as you receive the `sender`, you could just have one that identified which button was pressed? Also, could you post all the code for ToolbarVC.m and AppViewController.m?

Comment: I would have posted all the code, but it's extensive, and didn't want to have all the unrelated code filling the question up.  As far as buttons go, I could do that, but they are named differently...I just changed the names for here.  The code for ToolbarVC only has synthesize for the properties, release methods in dealloc, and in viewdidLoad it resizes the buttons and changes the titles.  In AppViewController I've imported the header and created a variable named photoToolbarVC this way: ToolbarVC* photoToolbarVC;

Comment: Do you have `@synthesize button1, button2, button3, button4;` in your `@implementation` block ?

Comment: I know all the properties work, because I use them in ToolbarVC's viewDidLoad when it's created.  E.g, [self.button1 setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Hated.  I found it.  Turns out the reference was being released and could be accessed.  Two days over a release statement.  To make things worse, I find it an hour after I post here. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hated. I found it. Turns out the reference was being released and could be accessed. Two days over a release statement. To make things worse, I find it an hour after I post here. :(